# Check if variable is the empty string

Tags: r, string

In a script I try to get running sometimes are variables being filled with `''` (which means: completely empty), e.g.

```
variable <- ''
```

Does anyone know of a method to check if variable has the value `''`?

`is.null(variable)` doesn't seem to work. `''` is not the same as `NULL`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`''` is an empty character. It does *not* mean “completely empty” – that is indeed `NULL`.

To test for it, just check for equality:

```
if (variable == '') …
```

However, the error you’re getting,

> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

means that there’s a *missing value* in your variable, i.e. `NA`. `if` cannot deal with missing values. An `NA` occurs as a result of many computations which themselves contain an `NA` value. For instance, comparing `NA` to any value (*even `NA` itself*) again yields `NA`:

```
variable = NA
variable == NA
# [1] NA
```

Since `if` expects `TRUE` or `FALSE`, it cannot deal with `NA`. If there’s a chance that your values can be `NA`, you need to check for this explicitly:

```
if (is.na(variable) || variable == '') …
```

However, it’s normally a better idea to exclude `NA` values from your data from the get-go, so that they shouldn’t propagate into a situation like the above.

Comment: Thanks! perhaps I asked the wrong question. this is the error i get: "Error in if (variable == "") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". Variable doesn't even seem to exist (must be an error in my script). Is there a way of checking if a variable exists?

Comment: @user1983395 Indeed, that’s a completely different question. Let me amend my answer.

Comment: An old thread, but I see that the response given to the specific error here is not correct. The "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" error does not mean that the variable doesn't exist, but instead that it is set to NA (the missing value code). If it didn't exist, the error would have been "object 'variable' not found." R complains because the logic is undefined; NA is neither equal to nor not equal to anything because it signifies that the value is missing and so could be either. Use `is.na()` and the boolean operators `&&` or `||` to define what it should do when a missing is found.

Comment: @Aaron Correct, thanks for pointing this out. I hadn’t actually paid attention to the specific error description.

Comment: If `variable` is a list, this test will give the following warning: `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`. One may want to test with `all(variable = ''))` instead, if one wants to test the entire list for empty strings, and to avoid the warning.

Comment: @PatrickT Yes, the answer assumes the variable is of type `character`. Lists behave fundamentally differently. Do note that your comparison is missing an `=`: it should be `==`, not `=`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, True about `==`, I mistyped! Any reasonable strategy to check if a variable is `''`? The OP does **NOT** assume that the variable is of type `character`, so the variable could be a list, a vector, etc.. Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickT Very (very!) few exceptions aside, the type of a variable in a given piece should be well-known and fixed. R is unfortunately unhelpful here, but it’s the programmer’s job to keep track of that information when writing code. There’s no general solution to deal with arbitrary types, the code by necessity needs to make assumptions, and it’s totally OK if code fails if the user violates these assumptions (this is known as [fail-fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast)).

Comment: Thanks a lot Konrad, great programming tip!

Answer (score 3):

In `stringi` package there is function for this.

```
require(stringi)    
stri_isempty(c("A",""))
```

You can also install this package from github:
https://github.com/Rexamine/stringi

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to both check and replace these values with `NA`s all at once, as is usually the case, just use `dplyr::na_if()`:

```r
variable <- ''
dplyr::na_if(variable, "")
#> [1] NA
```